# Incoming values to serial port are sometime corrupted or missing

Tags: c++, arduino

I have written simple bluetooth transmitter and receiver on two arduino nano v3 boards. Bluetooth modules are HM-10 connected into hardware serial ports. It works, but on receiver side I often receive corrupted values and many values are missing. Where is a problem:

I am beginner in arduino. If it is possible a need to explain deeply. Thanks.

Transmitter code:

```
const long waitingInterval = 20000;
unsigned long lastSend = micros();

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(19200);
  Serial.println("Started");
}

bool delay() {
  if(micros() >= lastSend + waitingInterval) {
    lastSend = micros();
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

void loop()
{

  if(delay()) {
    String mil = String(millis());
    String sendingText = mil + ";" + mil + ";" + mil + ".";
    Serial.println(sendingText);
  }

}
```

Output of transmitter serial monitor interface:

```
10548;10548;10548.
10568;10568;10568.
10589;10589;10589.
10609;10609;10609.
10629;10629;10629.
10649;10649;10649.
10670;10670;10670.
10690;10690;10690.
10711;10711;10711.
10730;10730;10730.
10750;10750;10750.
10771;10771;10771.
10791;10791;10791.
10812;10812;10812.
10831;10831;10831.
10852;10852;10852.
10872;10872;10872.
10893;10893;10893.
10913;10913;10913.
10933;10933;10933.
10953;10953;10953.
10974;10974;10974.
10994;10994;10994.
11014;11014;11014.
11034;11034;11034.
11055;11055;11055.
11075;11075;11075.
11096;11096;11096.
11115;11115;11115.
```

Receiver code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);
  Serial.println("Started");
}

void loop() {

  if(Serial.available()) {

    String incomingData = String();
    char incomingChar = Serial.read();

    if(incomingChar == '.') {
      incomingData = bufferString;
      Serial.print(bufferString);
      bufferString = String();
    } else {
      bufferString += String(incomingChar);
      return;
    }
}
```

Output of receiver serial monitor interface:

```
10548;10548;10548
10568;10568;10568
10589;10589;10589
10609;10609;10609
10629;10629;10629
106410771
10791;10791;10791
10812;10812;10812
10831;10831;10831
10852;10852;10852
10872;10872;10872
10893;10893;11034;11034;11034
11055;11055;11055
11075;11075;11075
11096;11096;11096
11115;11115;11115
```

Comment: How are you ensuring that your buffer is not being modified while it is being read? I don't see *any* synchronization in your code to ensure that.

Comment: Hmm. I hadn't known that it must be synchronised. What is easiest way for it?

Comment: You have more than one thread of execution accessing the same thing. How could you *not* realize that that would need synchronization? Easiest way to fix would *probably* be a mutex.

Comment: I have already tried this: https://www.hackster.io/feilipu/using-freertos-multi-tasking-in-arduino-ebc3cc but I have same problem.

Comment: Why don't you use `Serial.readln()` to get the whole line up to the newline?

Comment: @JesperJuhl, do you know what is Arduino and how receiving Serial data works?

Comment: @MarkSetchell `'class HardwareSerial' has no member named 'readln'`

Comment: Please check the Arduino documentation as it explains exactly how to use `serial.available()`: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/available/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is simply calling Serial.available() simply returns the number of bytes available to be read in the buffer; it could be exactly the number of bytes you need, it could be less, or more. Because of this, you might read extra data, too little, or too much data. More so, in higher level transmission protocols sometimes after a device receives data it will send an ACK(acknowledgement) back to the sender, saying it is ready for more data.

Edit** It should also be noted that the comment talking about mutex's isn't correct. Mutexes are typically used to synchronize code across multiple threads of execution on the **same** device. The key is that they are a shared resource across the thread's heap space. This is **NOT** the case when using two different arduino devices; thus, even if you could use them, it would be useless.

For your code, I would suggest the following edits to the transmitter:

```
#define MIN_TIMEOUT 3
void recieveAck(){
  bool validAck = false;
  uint8_t timeout_cnt = 0x00;
  while(timeout_cnt < MIN_TIMEOUT){
    //Wait for receiving device to respond with two bytes then send next
    char incomingBytes[2];
    Serial.readBytes(incomingBytes, 0x02);
    if(incomingBytes[0] == 0xBB && incomingBytes[1] == 0xCC)
      break;
    timeout_cnt++;
  }
}
void loop()
{

  if(delay()) {
    String mil = String(millis());
    String sendingText = mil + ";" + mil + ";" + mil + ".";
    Serial.println(sendingText);
    recieveAck();
  }
}
```

And to the receiver:

```
#define NEXT_INC_SIZE 2 //Expects one byte at a time
void sendAck(){
  char outData[2];
  outData[0] = 0xBB;
  outData[1] = 0xCC;
  Serial.write(outData, 2); //Write the ack data
}
void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() >= NEXT_INC_SIZE){
    char incomingBytes[2];
    Serial.readByte(incomingBytes, NEXT_INC_SIZE); //Read exactly how many bytes you need
    //Do stuff with the data here....
    sendAck();
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try it. But what about packet loss? For example. If ack would loss it will get stuck.

Comment: @JaSHin You really shouldn't be experiencing packet loss across the serial bus. That being said, I've updated the code with an ack timeout. Loop up Serial.setTimeout() for more info. It will default to 1 second.

Comment: I send it by bluetooth. I think some packet loss is possible or not?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, packet loss is always possible. I was also under the impression this was over a physical serial port. If this is being transmitted over-air via Bluetooth, it depends on BT library you're using. The Bluetooth standard dictates that all data sent must send an ACK once received. More so, all packets have a CRC that are verified to guarantee received data is correct.

Comment: I don't use any library. Bluetooth is connected directly into hw serial port. Maybe it is problem of bluetooth fw.

Comment: I little don't understand `NEXT_INC_SIZE` Is it size of `act` bytes or all data? Because my sending string `11115;11115;11115` has 18 bytes. Do I need modify this constant or not?

Comment: Becase if I try to read chars from `Serial` the output isn't correct. This is a code: https://pastebin.com/rncinvv4

Comment: NEXT_INC_SIZE is the size, in bytes, of what you expect the next packet to be. That is also 18 bytes of data when sending Strings. Instead, when sending just integers, send it as 3 payloads of uint16_t's. This will only be 6 bytes and is a better way to go about things. The data is in a more intuitive form, and you don't have to mess with so many string conversions. Instead of Serial.println() use Serial.write();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198159/discussion-between-jashin-and-btables).